# ng-model not updating when input values are populated from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I have a form where there are many inputs fields type="text" and I would need some
of the inputs where its value should be populated using clickevent. So I gave a
classname for specific inputs which is specialinputs.

```
       Below is the input field
       <input type="text" class="specialinputs" ngvalue="DataFields1" 
        ngmodel="DataFields1"> 
       </input>

        Below is the javascript code
        var myinputs = document.getElementsByClassName("specialinputs")
        for (i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
         myinputs[i].value = "Mytext"; 
         }
```

This works,Mytext is being populated. but my input field ng-model is not getting
updated, when i save the form , the values are not getting saved. Iam using angularjs

Answer (score 0):

it's because angular scope don't know about your changes
so you need to [tell him about them](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

```
var myinputs = document.getElementsByClassName("specialinputs")
    for (i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
     myinputs[i].value = "Mytext"; 
    }
$scope.$apply();
```